# Synchronizing multiple RTSP streams with Cudacodec VideoReader?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, rtsp

Camera broadcast comes from 4 different fpga's with rtsp. I'm starting to get the broadcasts by connecting to all of them from different ip's. I made myself an ntp server for synchronization and connected FPGA's to this server and they all use the same time. However, when the connections come and I start pressing the screen, they are not synchronous. I can take any time stamp and sync using buffer. But I was not able to get any timestamp with videoreader. How can I achieve synchronization?

Ubuntu 20.04, opencv 4.5.3, QT creator, c++

Note: I have to use VideoReader. I cannot decode videos that come with another library.

```
void Widget::on_StartStream_clicked(){

    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> videoReader[4];

    namedWindow("OpenGL Output", WINDOW_OPENGL);
    setWindowProperty("OpenGL Output", WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat MergedOutput(3120 * 2, 4208 * 2, CV_8UC4);

    try{

        int index = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < 8; i+=2){
            string rtspPathFpga = "rtsp://172.16.1.10" + to_string(i) + ":900" + to_string(i) + "/camera_1";
            cout << "i: " << i << endl;
            videoReader[index++] = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(rtspPathFpga);
        }

        while (true) {
            tryReconnection:
            i = 0;
            try {
                do{
                    videoReader[i]->nextFrame(videoFrames[i]);
                    i++;
                }while(i < 4);

            } catch (exception ex) {
                cout << "Try Reconnection for: " << ((i*2) + 1) << endl;
                string rtspPathFpga = "rtsp://172.16.1.10" + to_string((i*2) + 1) + ":900" + to_string((i*2) + 1) + "/camera_1";
                videoReader[i].release();
                videoReader[i] = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(rtspPathFpga);
                goto tryReconnection;
            }

            videoFrames[0].copyTo(MergedOutput(cv::Rect(0, 0, videoFrames[0].cols, videoFrames[0].rows)));
            videoFrames[1].copyTo(MergedOutput(cv::Rect(videoFrames[0].cols, 0, videoFrames[1].cols, videoFrames[1].rows)));
            videoFrames[2].copyTo(MergedOutput(cv::Rect(0, videoFrames[1].rows, videoFrames[2].cols, videoFrames[2].rows)));
            videoFrames[3].copyTo(MergedOutput(cv::Rect(videoFrames[2].cols, videoFrames[3].rows, videoFrames[3].cols, videoFrames[3].rows)));
            //cout << fpga1.size() << endl;
            imshow("OpenGL Output",MergedOutput);

            if (waitKey(1) == 'q') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }catch(string ex){
        cout << "camera 2: " << endl;
        cout << "An exception occurred." << ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBMjBKwVaUk&t=28s) is an implentation of how to decode an rtsp stream via on cudacodec. Thaty may help

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thank you for sharing. Actually the problem is; Frames are coming but they are not synchronous. They are looking in the same direction with certain intersections in 4 cameras. I'm trying to play them all in sync.

Comment: Depending on how accurately you need to synch, and at what point you need to synch, this can be quite a complicated problem. Synching cameras is something studios and production houses have looked at form some time, and multi camera 3D and VR is also looking at. It might be good to look at how it is solved there to get a feel - e.g.: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/video/tips-and-solutions/timecode-versus-sync-how-they-differ-and-why-it-matters